# Android custom camera previews as bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I am making a game that shows the current camera preview as the background. My 2D game engine (e3roid) can use textures from bitmaps. If I can't get a pain bitmap from the camera, I can use a library to turn it into a bitmap, so it doesn't matter what kind of data I get back from the camera preview. My question is is it possible to get a preview from the camera as image data without using the default intent or SurfaceView? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

try this

`camera=Camera.open();
    camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback()
    {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] bytes, Camera camera) 
       {
       //bytes=preview data;
       }
     });
   camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
   camera.startPreview();`

OR try
 opencv(opencv.org)